# How to execute the batch file? On double click it do not execute but creates two unknown file

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome, batch, batch-file

When i double click any .bat file it does not execute anymore (none of .bat file is executable anymore). I tried all the SO/SU answers with regedit but none of them fixed it yet.

my bat file contain as following.

```
@start /b cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk --user-data-dir=C:\iplay --disable-pinch --force-renderer-accessibility --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

Can anyone please help?

**EDIT:** i also verified as following

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat should have a default value of batfile 

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command should have a default value of "%1" %* Also you should *not* see a key named UserChoice under 

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat
```

Comment: Then you've missed the point that start uses the first double quoted string as the windows title, avoided by inserting a dummy empty pair `start "" ...`

Comment: Is this happening to all bat files, or only this one? If it is happening only with this one, it is just a code problem - fix your bat and it will be ok. To help track errors on bat files, you can run it from inside cmd prompt - there you will probably see the error message...

Comment: Add the word Pause to the last line of the bat. Now the window will stay open after the cmd is done, then you can read any errors mentioned by Leonardo.

Comment: It is happening to ALL Bat file. I also checked `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat should have a default value of batfile
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command should have a default value of "%1" %*

Also you should *not* see a key named UserChoice under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat` but still same all .bat files are not executable.

Comment: i added pause. But .bat file even do not execute at all from command prompt nor by double clicking.

Comment: Any stable .bat file which works on any other computer do not run on that computer at all. i try with command prompt or double click, nothing happen. it stop executing. it was working before but suddenly stop working for 1 week. I checked all registry but i cant find any fix. i also tried all SO, SU answers but none of them were helping me to fix it yet.

Comment: @YumYumYum why did you not include the details from your comments in the question itself?  Please include -all- relevant details such as what you have already tried etc.  It's not clear if the items you note were in the registry and if you fixed it and restarted.

Comment: Please check PATHEXT environment variable. It should contain .BAT and .CMD. Also please describe what exactly happening when you run .bat files. Can you run cmd.exe? What will happen if you try to run .bat file directly from there?

Comment: What happens if you runt he contents of the .BAT file from the command line? Does Chrome launch?

Comment: Command line or not command line. none of the .BAT file run